# Finding a Subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ $\times$ $\mathbb{Z}_4$ Not of the Form $H \times K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I need some help finishing out this problem. The question is:

Find a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ $\times$ $\mathbb{Z}_4$ that is not of the form $H \times K$, where $H \le \mathbb{Z}_6$ and $K \le \mathbb{Z}_4$.

This is what I have so far:

The subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ are {0}, <2>, <3>, and $\mathbb{Z}_6$ = <1>, and the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_4$ are {0}, <2>, and $\mathbb{Z}_4$ = <1>. This means that both $H$ and $K$ are one of these subgroups. So that means I need to find a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ $\times$ $\mathbb{Z}_4$ that isn't a "combination" of these subgroups, right? Where I'm having trouble is finding the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_6$ $\times$ $\mathbb{Z}_4$. I can only think of the ones involving the combinations of their respective subgroups. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Think about the element $(3,2)$.

Comment: Does that not just give you $\langle 3\rangle\times\langle 2\rangle$?

Comment: @ElliotG uhm... No. Yours has four elements.